# Headless Ubuntu MATE Raspberry Pi 3 Install?

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, headless

I'm trying to use my fresh Ubuntu MATE 16.04 Raspberry Pi 3 without a display or keyboard. So I created an empty file called ssh in `/boot` directory. But still I'm getting a ssh connection refused error. My Pi3 has a static local IP. I used ssh to log in to previous Raspbian OS without a problem.

Comment: Maybe there is no ssh server. Have you tried to install `openssh-server` in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 in your Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: i don't really know how i can install `openssh-server` since i can't do the first fresh boot without a monitor and keyboard (headless)

Answer (score 6):

[Here is the answer from the Ubuntu MATE official site](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)

> SSH
>
> Since Ubuntu MATE 16.04.2 the OpenSSH server is disabled by default.
>   If you want to enable SSH you can use `raspi-config` to create a file
>   called ssh on the `/boot` partition and reboot.

Comment: the OP is requesting a headless setup, this method need a physical monitor

Comment: I do not have a monitor or keyboard to enable SSH from `raspi-config`...
in Raspbian, you simply create an empty file in /boot and name it ssh. after that you can login to the Pi from any computer using the terminal to SSH in.

So in there no way to login to Ubuntu Mate 16.04.02 using SSH in a fresh install? Or is it necessary to have a Monitor & Keyboard?

Comment: Just mount the SD-card on another computer and create an (emtpy) file  `ssh` (without dot!) on the boot partition.

Comment: Did not work for me at first boot. Tried to ssh with the user `pi`